# In R, for all columns count factors/characters occurence, group by key

Tags: r

This question probably needs solving with `data.table` or `dplyr`. I have a dataset (data frame) which looks like this:

```
summary(mooc_events)
 signup_id         time                source               event        
 Min.   :     1   Min.   :2013-10-27   browser:3869940   access    :3112191  
 1st Qu.: 18721   1st Qu.:2013-12-19   server :4287337   discussion: 649259  
 Median : 48331   Median :2014-05-30                     navigate  :1009309  
 Mean   : 63476   Mean   :2014-04-05                     page_close:1237883  
 3rd Qu.:110375   3rd Qu.:2014-06-15                     problem   :1261170  
 Max.   :200905   Max.   :2014-08-01                     video     : 796958  
                                                         wiki      :  90507  
    artefact_sha         
 Length:8157277    
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character
```

One signup_id have multiple events, so there are many rows which starts with the same signup_id.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get an aggregated dataset (data.table or data frame) with as much columns as there are distinct values per particular column, all grouped by `signup_id`, so for this data it would look like this:

```
signup_id, source_browser, source_server, event_access, event_discussion, ... , event_wiki, artefact_sha_{first_element_in_whole_dataset}, ..., artefact_sha_{last_element_in_whole_dataset}

1, 23, 37, 9, 0, ..., 3, 7, ..., 1
2, 2, 7, 2, 2, ..., 1, 0, ..., 0
```

in other words, it's counting occurrences for given set of columns, grouped by single column `signup_id`, I'm not interesting in grouping by e.g. both signup_id and source.

Column naming is not strict (`_` can be substituted by anything which makes sense).

(let's skip the time column at the moment)

Best regards and thanks upfront.

Comment: I can't think of a problem that `dplyr` solves that you _couldn't_ solve in base R, unless it's performance-related. That does not, however, mean that you _should_ use base R to solve it.

Comment: Also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25812054/2954547) combined with [`group_by`](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/functions/group_by) should give you what you need if you want to go the `dplyr` route. If you manage to figure it out on your own, I'd encourage you to post the solution as an answer to your own question. It will help future users.

Comment: I mentioned data.frame and dplyr because of both performance and code readability. I realize that base R is very often enough. I just saw lot of solutions in those packages and I thought it's worth mentioning names of packages..

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks for providing link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811756/summarizing-counts-of-a-factor-with-dplyr/25812054#25812054

Comment: is `artefact_sha` unique for every row?

Comment: there are actually around 5 thousand unique `artefact_sha`s in the dataset so I think I will exclude it as well and simply make one column with an aggregate - count unique `artefact_sha` per `signup_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more like a reshaping problem which could be solved using the tidyr and reshape2 libraries.

Reshaping with tidyr and counting occurences with reshape2 :

My example doesn't include `artefact_sha` because I didn't understand what you want to do with it.

```
library(dplyr) # Or library(magrittr) for the pipe syntax
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(42)
mooc_events <- data.frame(signup_id = rep(1:3, each = 5), 
                    time = Sys.Date(), 
                    source = sample(c("browser", "server"), 15, rep = TRUE), 
                    event = sample(c("access", "discussion", "navigate"), 15, rep = TRUE), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mooc_events.m <- 
  mooc_events %>% 
  gather(key, value, -c(signup_id, time)) %>% 
  unite(var, key, value, sep = "_")

myTable <- dcast(mooc_events.m, signup_id ~ var, fun.aggregate = length)

> myTable
  signup_id event_access event_discussion event_navigate source_browser source_server
1         1            1                2              2              1             4
2         2            2                0              3              1             4
3         3            0                3              2              3             2
```

Comment: Sweet. This is what I was looking for, and for sure I need to spend some time studying this feature. After piping gather and unite I get `Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped `. Should I be worried about it ? And after dcast: `Using var as value column: use value.var to override.` Result data looks really fine, but I don't get the warnings.

Comment: The 1st warning result from the using of factors see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688897/reshape2-melt-warning-message, be carefull with this one you maybe can experience strange behaviours. And the second message is OK, (it's not a warning), though you can hide it using `value.var = "var"` in `dcast`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work.  It's a combination of `dplyr` and `reshape2`.  This only generates some of the variables you have.  To include the rest of the variable you want to count across, just add them into the `group_by` call and the `dcast`, ie. `dcast(tst, signup_id ~ source+event+...)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

## First get counts for groupings of variables
tst <- mooc_events %>% group_by(signup_id, source, event) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(count=n())

## Then reshape data long -> wide
dcast(tst, signup_id ~ source+event)

#    signup_id browser_access browser_navigate browser_video browser_wiki
# 1          1              2               NA             1            2
# 2          2             NA               NA             2           NA
# 3          3              3                1            NA            3
# ...
#    server_access server_navigate server_video server_wiki
# 1             NA               1            3           1
# 2              3               2           NA           1
# 3             NA               4           NA           5

## Some sample data
mooc_events <- data.frame(
    signup_id=sample(1:10, 100, replace=T), 
    source=factor(sample(c("browser", "server"), 100, replace=T)),
    event=factor(sample(c("access","navigate","video","wiki"), 100, replace=T))
)
head(mooc_events)

#   signup_id  source    event
# 1         5 browser     wiki
# 2         4  server navigate
# 3         1 browser navigate
# 4         7 browser   access
# 5         8  server   access
# 6         5 browser     wiki
```